# What are people using to connect SSD drives from a camera to Thunderbolt or Firewire?

Tags: mac, firewire, bmcc, ssd, thunderbolt

We're shooting on a Blackmagic Cinema Camera, and at the moment are using the guts of a little portable drive enclosure as our cradle for transferring to our Macs via Firewire 800. It's got a very guerrilla vibe to it, but it's not exactly what I want to see when I'm transferring irreplaceable footage.

I've looked around, but there doesn't seem to be any purpose built SSD cradle for Firewire 800 or Thunderbolt (our editing machines are being replaced by Thunderbolt-only ones), only USB3. Has anyone got any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HighPoint RocketStor RS5212](http://www.highpoint-tech.com/USA_new/series_RS5212-overview.htm) is a Thunderbolt Dock that will accept two hard drives or SSDs.

I would not use FireWire for SSDs, unless you don't have USB 3.0 and you're on a budget. USB 3.0 is often fast enough to get the maximum out of your SSD, FireWire not.

Comment: Firewire 800 is for the older machines that don't have thunderbolt. They're rusted-on mac users here, so no USB 3.0.

Comment: Oh well in that case ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, seeing as you are already using Black Magic stuff, you could always use the Black Magic Multi-Dock.  It supports 4 SSDs and Thunderbolt.  The Black Magic HyperDeck Studio Pro is another option.  It has thunderbolt connectivity and accepts two SSDs and can even handle the recording for you as well if you feed a line in to it.

Comment: Close, but probably overkill. Maybe the hyperdeck shuttle might be the go, but I'm hoping for something in between Jason's answer and yours.

Comment: @stib - I don't think the hyperdeck shuttle connects to a computer.  You'd want the Multi-Dock if you are looking specifically to transfer off SSDs that you recorded to.

Answer (score 0):

I use a [seagate thunderbolt adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006P1QWOQ).  It works.  It's portable.  It's cheap.

Comment: Close, but it's still kinda hacky, it's not that different to what we're using at the moment.